# Install Python 3.5 on Mac for IntelliJ IDEA / PyCharm

Tags: python, macos, intellij-idea

I'm using a third-party Python package that supports Python 3.5, but not 3.6.  I've got Python 2.7 installed from my OS vendor (it's a Mac), and Python 3.6 installed through [homebrew](https://brew.sh/).

What's the best way for me to install 3.5 and configure IntelliJ IDEA (using its Python plugin, so it's basically equivalent to [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/)) to use it?

Comment: I think, the best way is to install Python from the official website first and then configure the IDE.

Comment: What conflicts might arise between that (https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-353/) and my existing Python 3.6?  It looks like they might try to create some of the same files.

Comment: none, you can have all possible versions of Python installed, and they won't conflict with each other. The only issue might be installing libraries for some particular version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can install as many Python distributions as you want and they all located in `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions`.  However, pip3 will only be linked to the **last** python distribution you installed, not the latest. For example, in my case, my pip3 is the module in python3.5 because I installed it after 3.6. If you want to use a package for a specific version, run `$ python3.x -m package`. `python3.6 -m pip install`, for example.